# Stop user from progressing in a multi-step jQuery form if datepicker value is blank

Tags: jquery

How would I validate the "date picker" field on step 3 of my multi-step jQuery form. Right now the field just checks if **$('#datepicker').val()** is empty by sending an alert but still lets the user carry on until the next stage. How do you prevent the user from carrying on if the field is blank?

It can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/xSkgH/28/

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty simple, just return `false;`

```
if (!$('#datepicker').val()){
     //alert('no date!');   
     return false;                
}
```

#### Fixed [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Starx/xSkgH/33/)

#### Updated [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Starx/xSkgH/34/) with inline Message

```
if (!$('#datepicker').val()){
    $("#errorMessage").html('no date!');   
    return false;                
}
```

Comment: Instead of an alert can an inline message also pop up?

Answer (score 1):

Hi try this fiddle.......

http://jsfiddle.net/xSkgH/32/

Add **return false** to prevent submitting to next step.

Answer (score 1):

Use the datepicker's `getDate` method which returns the current date for the datepicker or null if no date has been selected.